# What does getExternalFilesDir() do if there's no SD card installed?

Tags: java, android

I am making an project that use AudioRecord API to record voice and do some processing with produced PCM-16bit data.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
private void startRecording() { 

final int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);
final byte raw_data[] = new byte[bufferSize];

final File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "test.pcm");

if (!file.mkdirs()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Directory not created");
}
if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}

recorder.startRecording();
isRecording = true;

recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (isRecording) {
            int read = recorder.read(raw_data, 0, bufferSize);
            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {

                try {
                    os.write(raw_data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "run: close file output stream !");
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, "AudioRecorder Thread");

recordingThread.start();
}
```

From my understanding, `final File file = new FilegetExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "test.pcm");`, this line of code will create a file called "test.pcm", and it is located at whatever the path refereed by `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)`.

I assume it is a Music Folder but what I don't understand is that my Android device currently has no SD or any external storage installed so how come this code still work? I am still able to playback the voice using AudioTrack API.

Since I need to do some processing of the stored PCM file, I wonder where does this file actually stored on my device and how can I access it.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of `getExternalFilesDir(type)`:

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the primary shared/external storage device where the application can place persistent files it owns.

Assuming you are running your app on a phone or a tablet, even if your device does not have an SD card mounted, it does have onboard storage. From your app's perspective, the onboard storage is the primary storage device in this case.

Furthermore, I suggest reading the whole documentation of [`getExternalFilesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) to get a deeper insight.